# Can I swap chargers?

Tags: battery, nokia-lumia-930, charging, nokia-lumia-720

I previously had a Nokia Lumia 720 and I still have it's charger. Recently I got a Lumia 930.

Output of 720 charger is 5V and 1.3 A
Output of 930 charger is 5V and 1.5 A

As my 930 is a Chinese version, it came with a really extrange conector and it doesn't exist in my country. Is it ok if I use the charger of my Lumia 720 with my Lumia 930?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using different USB chargers should be no problem.

I have many different Nokia, Dell, Apple, etc USB adapters and use them to charge different devices all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Note that some chargers (I have here a HTC USB charger 5V/200mA) deliver less power than you might need. Charging can be very slow or even never complete. For the 930 you need the 1500mA (although the 1300mA will suffice I think).